# PostgreSQL: How to query for the last day of the current month?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to return the last day of the current month formatted as digits. How would I write the SQL query in Postgres to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  TO_CHAR(
    DATE_TRUNC('month', CURRENT_DATE)  -- first day of current month
      + INTERVAL '1 month'             -- first day of next month
      - INTERVAL '1 day',              -- last day of current month
    'DD'                               -- format last day of month
  ) last_day_of_month
```

Comment: Or if you want an integer value just `extract(day from ...)` instead of `to_char`.

Comment: '1 month - 1 day' will do as well

Answer (score 0):

Use a

`LEFT OUTER JOIN sales_registrations FROM months`

(instead of your right join). That way you will pick up the records from sales_registrations where there is no join and all those fields will have `NULL` values.

If you don't want to see NULLS in the results, 
use a `SUM` and a `CASE` :

`SUM(CASE WHEN some_field_from_sales_registrations IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as c`